# Using setAdapter method on autoCompleteTextView will be right during searching the list items from listView in android?

Tags: android, listview, autocompletetextview

I implemented code for searching the items from `listView` using `autoCompleteTextView`. The code is as follows :

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    String[] dataArray = new String[] {"India","America", "Russia", "China", "Nepal", "Japan"};
    private AutoCompleteTextView actv;  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataArray);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        actv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        actv.setThreshold(1);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {   
        @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, If you have set your adapter then you can set your `AutoCompleteTextView` with this. Are you getting any issue?

Comment: No. I want to clear my doubt regarding this. Thanks. :-)

Comment: No, most likely you should either use `SearchView` or `EditText` and filter out your `ListView` by calling `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)` method

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your suggestion. I have also used it. Both are working well.